# How do I make the panel transparent in GNOME Classic mode?

Tags: gnome, panel, transparency

Hi I don't know to make the top panel in Gnome classic transparent, I tried to right click then properties then change the transparency there but the indicator applet menu complete stays in the ambiance theme... any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a well-known bug of the classic GNOME environment, as far as I know there is nothing to do about it. You used to be able to patch the panel code so it becomes properly transparent, though it will not work anymore for GNOME 3.

Comment: Can you please post the link to the bug?

Comment: I couldn't find it, but I did came across this small tutorial: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43673/how-to-make-the-gnome-panels-in-ubuntu-totally-transparent/ . You need Compiz, though.